# CSS - 4 columns (fixed fluid fluid fixed)

Tags: css

I have seen examples of three columns (fixed fluid fixed).  However, I need an example of a four column solution.

The two outer columns are fixed.
The two inner columns are fluid.

Fixed  |  Fluid  | Fluid  |  Fixed

Comment: What do you mean by "fluid"? Would you like to have the two "fluid" columns to share the remaining space? 50%/50%?

Comment: Correct... so if I set the width (300px, 400px or whatever) for the first and last columns, the middle two columns fill the space in between adjusting accordingly to screen resizing / resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
.first, .last {
    width: 300px;
}
.middle {
    width: calc(50% - 300px);
}
```

You may want to apply vendor prefixes too.

Comment: Oh Cool.  So I did a Google search and found this.

http://jonkemp.com/css/cross-browser-css-calc.html

Any other resources for calc cross browser?

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation), [HTML5 rocks](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/CSS-layout-gets-smarter-with-calc)

Comment: @bjb568 calc is not a standard . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc , you may consider cross browser compatibility before posting , The following features are at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period: ‘calc()’, ‘toggle()’, ‘attr()’. source : http://www.w3.org

Comment: What? So we shouldn't use HTML5? Calc won't be dropped, that would be crazy since it has implementations everywhere and major websites rely on it.

Comment: @ProllyGeek The answer is not incorrect, you should maybe appreciate the time someone has taken out of theirs to help someone, unless you have a better answer I would suggest you not criticise another's correct answer

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="framecontentLeft">
    <div class="innertube">
        <h1>Left Frame 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="framecontentRight">
    <div class="innertube">
        <h1>Right Frame 4</h1>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="maincontent">
    <div class="inner1">
        <h1>Middle Frame 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
        <h1>Middle Frame 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#framecontentLeft, #framecontentRight{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}

#framecontentRight{
    left: auto;
    right: 0; 
    width: 150px;
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
}

#maincontent{
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner1{
    height: 100%;
    background:red;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.inner2{
    background:green;
    height: 100%;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/8CLBn/2/)

Comment: Using position:fixed like this could break some layouts.

Comment: OP wants fixed | fluid | fluid | fixed layout.

Answer (score 0):

I like flexbox better than `calc`, if you can use it. It’s more… flexible.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed
    </div>

    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid
    </div>

    <div class="fluid">
        Fluid
    </div>

    <div class="fixed">
        Fixed
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
}

.fixed {
    width: 15em;
}

.fluid {
    flex: 1;
}
```

[Dabblet.](http://dabblet.com/gist/11161874) This, of course, makes all columns the same height, and if you can assume that, doing it without flexbox is also no problem given one more container (noting that if the fluid elements won’t necessarily be taller than the fixed ones, then you should give the inner container a `max-height`):

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="fixed left">
        Fixed
    </div>

    <!-- Fluid container! No, you don’t have to call it this. -->
    <div class="bottle">
        <div class="fluid">
            Fluid
        </div>

        <div class="fluid">
            Fluid
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed right">
        Fixed
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

.fixed {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15em;
}

.fixed.left {
    left: 0;
}

.fixed.left {
    right: 0;
}

.bottle {
    margin: 0 15em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fluid {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

And, of course, if `.bottle` overflows, you’ll need some kind of clearing `::after`.